# c++ executable program test

Tags: c++, executable

I have been following some tutorials for c++ game programing. I am kind of new to c++ and I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express IDE. I'm working on creating a game, and when I run the program through the IDE, it shows the grass sprites as expected. But when I run the .exe file from the Release folder, it shows weird images. and when I run the .exe file from the debug folder I get a grey screen. Can anybody tell me why this is happening?[image: FROM IDE]

[image: FROM RELEASE FOLDER .EXE FILE]

[image: FROM DEBUG FOLDER .EXE FILE]

Comment: It is difficult to debug without a few more details. Consider including some code and maybe information about your setup? Good luck though.

Comment: Presumably you load some resources, and they would be in a different directory relative to the executable in all three cases unless you changed the working directory in the debugger options.  If I had to guess, they fail to load in the second two cases and you don't have enough error checking in the program to tell you that.

Answer (score 2):

I hazard to guess that your sprite images are kept as data files in your project folder. With that I offer the following premise:

The default run-location from the Visual Studio IDE is the *project* folder of the project which you're executing. That is, normally it executes from the directory where your **.vcproj** or **.vcprojx** file is kept (and that is often one folder below your solution directory folder, where your **.sln** file is kept).

If your project runs correctly from the IDE, but fails to run directly from the release folder, it is highly likely you are relying on project data files (images in your case) that are kept along side your source files in the project folder. When run from the Release folder, those files are no longer visible because your the Release folder is your working directory; not the project folder.

There are a number of ways to solve this problem, each with its own merits. A few options are:

**Post Build Step**

Make a post-build step for your project that copies your data files to the `$(TargetDir)` location with your project. These files will then be visible in the same directory as your executable.

- Benefit: Its easy.
- Drawback: It will always run if you click "build solution" even if the data files are "up-to-date."

**Custom Build Targets**

Add your data files to the project and write a  Custom Build script that performs the same copy, but also establishes an output dependency file(s).

- Benefit: Almost as easy as #1,  but a little more tedious.
- Drawback: You may have a lot of data files and each will require its own custom build step. (Note: you *can* multi-select all the data files in your project, and if you're creative with the built-in macros you can have them all use the "same" build rules and commands).

**Embedded Resources**

Add the data files as custom resources to your executable.

- Benefit: Your project no longer requires data files side-by-side with the executable since they are embedded in the resource table of your EXE module.
- Drawback: Custom code is required to dynamically load the custom resources from your executable's resource table rather than off-disk. It isn't difficult at all to do, but is additional work.

There are other options as well, but I hope this gives you some ideas to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I use VS2008 and try to answer your question. Right click on the project and select properties on the bottom of popup, then go to Debugging under Configuration properties. You can see command you run and arguments you pass in IDE. I guess you miss some parameters.